# Fastest implementation of Maximum Subarray Sum in R

Tags: r, performance

Dear community members,

I use a function of Maximum Subarray Sum (Kadane algorithm) very often in my tool. It is a bottleneck.

Could you tell me if the performance can be improved using some internal R tricks? It works faster in C++ - but I do not really want to add C++ code to my R-based tool...

```
maxSubArraySum <- function(x){
  bestSoFar = 0
  bestNow = 0
  bestStartIndexSoFar = -1
  bestStopIndexSoFar = -1
  bestStartIndexNow = -1
  for (i in 1:length(x)) {
    value = bestNow + x[i]
    if (value > 0) {
      if (bestNow == 0) {
        bestStartIndexNow = i
      }
      bestNow = value
    }
    else
      bestNow = 0
    
    if (bestNow > bestSoFar) {
      bestSoFar = bestNow
      bestStopIndexSoFar = i
      bestStartIndexSoFar = bestStartIndexNow
    }
  }
  return(c(bestSoFar, bestStartIndexSoFar, bestStopIndexSoFar))
}
```

Comment: Please provide illustrative example input. (It would be trivial to use Rcpp here. Are you sure you don't want to do that?)

Comment: @Roland - the input could be rnorm(100000) . I will go into Rcpp if nothing can be done here  - I am just so amazed by the efficiency of code by some R professionals that are able to put everything into a vector and give an immediate speed up, so decided to ask here =)

Comment: I don't see an option without a loop in R. There is a [function in the adagio package](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/adagio/versions/0.7.1/topics/maxsub) that you could use. It uses fortran code or an R-level `for` loop.

Comment: @Roland thank you! I'll proceed with Rcpp then. The problem with Rcpp is that it is that an app is "in production" and I can't anticipate problems with Rcpp installation on other systems - so will be with Adagio... =(

Comment: @Roland 200x speed up for this function only. I regret not using Rcpp before. Added "Rcpp" %in% rownames(installed.packages()) flag for the ones who can not install Rcpp.

Answer (score 2):

If  you do not want to use Rcpp, here is a faster plain-R vectorized implementation:

```r
fast_maxSubArraySum <- function(x) {
    csum = cumsum(x)
    cmin = cummin(csum)
    gaps = csum - cmin
    endPos = which.max(gaps)
    integralMax = gaps[endPos]
    startPos = which.min(cmin[1:endPos])+1
    integralMin = gaps[startPos-1]
    gap = integralMax - integralMin
    if(cmin[startPos] > 0) {
        startPos = 1
        gap = csum[endPos]
    }
    return(c(gap, startPos, endPos))
}
```

This version is more than 10 times faster than `maxSubArraySum` on my machine.
Note that the same strategy can also be used to write an even faster C++ version.